# How to specify alpha order when merging PDF files in Python?

Tags: python, pdf, python-3.6, pypdf

I am working with a folder containing 24 Word documents that need to be converted to PDF and then merged into 1 master PDF. I have a working Python script (version 3.6.2) with the PyPDF2 module that will do these first 2 steps almost perfectly, but when combining, the order of the PDFs seems random (and not in alphabetical order of filename, as they appear in the current working directory).

I've seen code online where people create a text file specifying the order of the merge, but this seems like a lot of extra work if you're working with a large number of files (what happens if I have 100 files that need to be merged next time?). Ideally, I'd like my script to merge the files *in the exact order that they appear in the directory.*

My entire script is rather long, so I won't copy all of it, but here's the final bit that shows the merge (and where I'd like to specify alpha order, if possible):

```
merger = PdfFileMerger()

for file in os.listdir(getcwd()):
    if file.endswith(".pdf"):
        print(file)
        merger.append(PdfFileReader(file),'rb')
merger.write("NewPDF.pdf")
```

Comment: ".. in the exact order that they appear in the directory." Which is sorted on what? Date/time, size, name, some other attribute? Does your `listdir` return the files in the order you want?

Comment: It's currently sorted alphabetically by name of file in the directory. And yes, the `listdir` does return them in the proper order, which is the strange thing. I'd think it would append in order - but it doesn't

Comment: I got curious to know how you got to convert Word documents to PDF with PyPDF2.

Comment: Sidenote: 3.6 is [no longer supported](https://devguide.python.org/versions/) (it's been EOL for over two years already), the oldest still support version is 3.8

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sort()`:

```
from PyPDF2 import PdfWriter
import os

merger = PdfWriter()
files = [file for file in os.listdir() if file.endswith(".pdf")]

files.sort()

for pdf in files:
 merger.append(pdf)

merger.write('merged-pdf2.pdf')
merger.close()
```